# Add Test Results with references to Test Plan, Test Suite, Test Case not working "ShallowReference" using azure rest api

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using Azure DevOps Services REST API 5.1 to create test runs in my DevOps Test Plan.

I first create a test run like the [documents here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

Postman request:

```
POST /{Organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?api-version=5.0 HTTP/1.1 Host: dev.azure.com 
Authorization: Basic xyz
Content-Type: application/json    
    {
        "name": "koko",
        "automated": true 
    }
```

I then add a test result to the previously created test Run. [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

Postman Request:

```
POST /{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/240/results?api-version=5.0 HTTP/1.1
Host: dev.azure.com
Authorization: Basic xyz
Content-Type: application/json

[
  {
    "Project": {
      "Id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-c748b3ba25f6",
      "Name": "Project",
      "Url": "https://dev.azure.com/xx/_apis/projects/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-c748b3ba25f6"
    },
    "StartedDate": "2020-07-07T16:25:56.4171217+03:00",
    "DurationInMs": 550,
    "Outcome": "Passed",
    "State": "Completed",
    "TestCase": {
      "Id": "6304",
      "Name": "TestCase",
      "Url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/testplan/Plans/6302/Suites/6303/TestCase/6304"
    },
    "TestRun": {
      "Id": "240",
      "Name": "koko",
      "Url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/240"
    },
    "Priority": 2,
    "CreatedDate": "2020-07-07T16:24:56.4171092+03:00",
    "TestCaseTitle": "TEST8",
    "TestPlan": {
      "Id": "6302",
      "Name": "Template",
      "Url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/testplan/Plans/6302"
    },
    "TestSuite": {
      "Id": "6303",
      "Name": "Template",
      "Url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/testplan/Plans/6302/Suites/6303"
    },
    "AutomatedTestName": "TEST8"
  }
]
```

The problem I'm facing is that the created test result does not show the referenced Test Plan, Test Case Id, and Test Suite.

Current Result:

[image]

Expected Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additionally, you need [Test points of your test case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/points/get%20points%20by%20query?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#by-test-case-id)  and [work item info (revision)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

Here is an example:

1. Create a test run with planned test points:

   ```
   https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{teamproject}/_apis/test/runs?api-version=5.1
   {
    "name": "NewTestRun",
    "automated": true, 
      "plan": {
    "id": "103"
    },
    "pointIds": [3]
   }
   ```
2. Add test result:

   ```
   https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{teamproject}/_apis/test/Runs/{RunId}/results?api-version=5.1

   [
    {
        "Priority": 2,  
        "State": "Completed",
        "outcome": "Passed",    
        "testCaseRevision": 3,
        "testCaseTitle": "Test 1",
        "testCase":
        {            
            "id": "106"
        },
        "testPoint":
        {            
            "id": "3"
        },
        "AutomatedTestName": "TEST8"
    }
   ]
   ```

Comment: @Shamari Aleksander Still, even after adding TestPointId, it is still not showing the referenced TestPlan, TestSuite and TestCase

Comment: Any more thoughts about this?

Comment: Thank you @Shamari Aleksander, much appreciated.