# How to Link Azure Pipeline Test Results to Test Cases

Tags: azure, junit, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pytest

I’m trying to link automated test results from a pipeline task PublishTestResults, to test cases in azure. That way I am able view the history of the test results through the test case

**Background**

These tests are automated with pytest and generate a Junit XML report to Azure. Please correct me if I am wrong but from what I found, there isn’t an argument or option or setting where azure is able to link these test cases automatically. Also the XML format Azure expects doesn’t contain a attribute for the id. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=trx%2Cyaml

I can’t associate these tests through visual studio since pytest is not supported. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops

**Problem**

I started using the Azure REST API and the azure devops python api, https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api . Got my build id, test run id associated to the pipeline build, test run from the id, test case id, and the test point id. Doing a **GET Test Result** returns the test result, and focusing on a particular object of the response.

```
"testCase": {
    "name": "test title"
},
```

However when I do a **PATCH Test Result** to update the test result with

```
"testCase": {
    "id": "5688",
    "name": "test title"
},
"testPoint": {
    "id": "296"
},
```

It does not update, and remains the same. I can confirm that I am able to update other fields, and I see the lastUpdatedDate updates as well. Referring to this call. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

I tried a manual test run, and was able to add test results with test case id's. However I couldn't edit the test case id's after. I tried adding a test result with test case id's to my automated test runs but that did not work

Anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong or a better way to go about linking test results to test cases in Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted to Visual Studio Developer Community Forum.

We pretty much have to go through the "Update Work Item" route. In order to link the automated test results with a test case, I added a relation link to the test result:

```
[
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/relations/-",
        "value": {
            "rel": "ArtifactLink",
            "url": "vstfs:///TestManagement/TcmResult/1234.100000",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Test Result"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

This will add a link from the test case to direct you to an invalid URL, so it just puts you on the Build Summary page. Not great since it's missing `/results` in the URL:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_build?buildId=1122&view=ms.vss-test-web.build-test-results-tab&runId=1234&resultId=100000&paneView=debug
```

But outside of that, this works.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this:

[Add Test Results with references to Test Plan, Test Suite, Test Case not working "ShallowReference" using azure rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62777775/add-test-results-with-references-to-test-plan-test-suite-test-case-not-working)

You will need to work with the [Test - Runs - Create API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP), which allows you to start a new test run, for a given Test plan. With this post operation you need to reference the test plan in question AND the test points, of each test case that you want the run to include. Test points is the way a test case is represented from the test plan / test suite point of view. So the think of test points as referenced test cases, where you get a new "local" id on the test plan - that you need to handle.

Now you have a test run, which has the state of "In Progress" - and it contains a list of the test points that should be tested. This enables you to fetch the list of test points that you should update with the given status, via the [Test - Results - List API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP). The result will yield a json array that you can traverse and assign the state of the test.

The tricky part is that now you need to do an update / patch of the test run, via the [Test - Results - Update API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP), make sure that you DON'T do a post operation as it will make new entries and newer complete the individual test cases.

Lastly you need to complete the test run via the [Test - Runs - Update API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP), to have the test run leave the "In Progress" state.