# How to associate Postman test results with Azure test plans Test Cases

Tags: postman, azure-pipelines, ado, newman

I have set of api tests written in postman. I run them in ADO release pipeline.
[release pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDXrl.png)
In the end I export test results to junit. I can see test results in Test Plans => Runs. But I cant find out how to associate test results with single tests

I did not find enough information on this topic. I mostly used chatGPT :)

I tried to associate test result by adding test case id to Name of test (example:  "[97] Users / User CRUD / Create User | Status code is 200" ), this did not work.

Does anyone have idea how to solve this, or some links?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

You can associate with test cases with types below: [What types of tests are supported?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops#q-what-types-of-tests-are-supported)

If your test are not included, as an alternative, you can:

1. in the publish test result task, add test case info in `test run title`.

[image]

Check the test run:

[image]

2. You could consider update the test case: [How to Link Azure Pipeline Test Results to Test Cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69829765/14996050)